# R apply function returns numeric value on date variables

Tags: r, date, dataframe, apply

I have a R dataframe which have sequence of dates. I want to create a dataframe from the existing one which consists of one month prior dates. 
For example let x be the initial dataframe

```
x = data.frame(dt = c("28/02/2000","29/02/2000","1/03/2000","02/03/2000"))
```

My required dataframe y would be

```
y = c("28/01/2000","29/01/2000","1/02/2000","02/02/2000")
```

The list is quite big so I don't want looping. I have created a inline function which works fine when I give individual dates.

```
datefun <- function(x) seq(as.Date(strptime(x,format = "%d/%m/%Y")), length =2, by = "-1 month")[2]

datefun("28/02/2000") gives "28/01/2000" as an output
```

But while I use it inside R apply it gives random numerical values.

```
apply(x,1,function(x) datefun(x))
```

The output for this is

```
[1] 10984 10985 10988 10989
```

I don't know from where these numbers are getting generated, am I missing something.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should not use `apply` since the result will be returned as a matrix. Matrices in R cannot store values of class `Date`. You have to use `lapply` instead. This returns a list of results. These results can be combined with `Reduce` and `c` to create a `Date` vector.

```
Reduce(c, lapply(x$dt, datefun))
# [1] "2000-01-28" "2000-01-29" "2000-02-01" "2000-02-02"
```

Comment: the only answer addressing the real problem here

Answer (score 4):

I believe that R internally is storing your dates as time elapsed since the UNIX epoch, which is January 1, 1970.  You can easily view your updated dates as readable strings using `as.Date` with an apporpriate origin, e.g.

```
y <- apply(x,1,function(x) datefun(x))
as.Date(y, origin='1970-01-01')

[1] "2000-01-28" "2000-01-29" "2000-02-01" "2000-02-02"
```

The gist here is that the numerical output you saw perhaps misled you into thinking that your date information were somehow lost.  To the contrary, the dates are stored in a numerical format, and it is up to you to tell R how you want to view that information as dates.

## Demo

Answer (score 4):

You could also skip your function with `lubridate`:

```
require(lubridate)
format(dmy(x$dt) %m+% months(-1),"%d/%m/%Y")
```